# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens posiblemente por execute(array)

Tags: php7, pdo

Me aparece el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Como digo en el título sospecho que el error puede ser al intentar pasarle los parámetros mediante  execute(array), que es la línea del error. La conexión es un objeto PDO.

Os dejo el código de la función, dentro de la clase **CRUD_Productos.php**:

```
public function setProducto(Producto_Modelo $producto){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->TablaDb (NOMBREPRODUCTO, CATEGORIA, SUBCATEGORIA, FAMILIAPRODUCTO, DESCRIPCIONCORTA, DESCRIPCIONLARGA, PRECIO, PRECIOANTERIOR, PRECIOINDI3U, PRECIOINDI5U, STOCK, DESTACADO, VIDEO, IMAGENPRINCIPAL, IMAGEN2, IMAGEN3, IMAGEN4, IMAGEN5, IMAGEN6) VALUES (?, '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')";
    $preparar = $this->Conexion->prepare($sql);
    /*echo "<p>Éste es el var_dump de la variable preparar:<br><b>";
    var_dump($preparar);
    echo "</b></p>";*/
    //var_dump(debug_backtrace());
    $preparar->execute(array($producto->getNombre(), $producto->getCategoria(), $producto->getSubcategoria(), $producto->getFamilia(), $producto->getDescripcionCorta(), $producto->getDescripcionLarga(), $producto->getPrecio(), $producto->getPrecioAnterior(), $producto->getPrecioU3U(), $producto->getPrecioU5U(), $producto->getStock(), $producto->getDestacado(), $producto->getVideo(), $producto->getImagenPrincipal(), $producto->getImagen2(), $producto->getImagen3(), $producto->getImagen4(), $producto->getImagen5(), $producto->getImagen6()));

    //var_dump(debug_backtrace());

    $num_rows = $preparar->rowCount();

    if($num_rows == 1){
        echo "¡<p>Se ha insertado correctamente el nuevo producto!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Ha habido algún error intentando insertar el nuevo producto.</p>";
    }
}
```

El ID no lo he puesto porque se supone que se crea automáticamente en la base de datos. Aún  así he  probado añadiéndole el id y sigue dándome el mismo error. Todos los precios están en formato *decimal(6,2)* en la base de datos, Destacado y  Stock, son *tinyint*, Descripción larga es *text* y el resto son todo *varchar*.

Así los he creado antes de llamar a la función desde **InsertarProducto_Controlador.php**:

```
    <?php
$miCon = new Conexion();//Conecta directo a la base de datos
$miProducto = new Producto_Modelo();//Instancia del Producto
$miCRUD = new CRUD_Productos($miCon->ConectarDB());
$imagenes = array('ImagenPrincipal', 'Imagen2', 'Imagen3', 'Imagen4', 'Imagen5', 'Imagen6');

foreach($imagenes as $imagen){
    if(($imagen == "ImagenPrincipal") && (isset($_FILES[$imagen])) && ($_FILES[$imagen]['name'] == "")): ?>
        <script>
            alert("¡Tienes que subir la IMAGEN PRINCIPAL!");
            window.location="../../NuevoProducto.php";
        </script>
    <?php endif;

    if($_FILES[$imagen]['name'] != ""){
        if($_FILES[$imagen]['size'] <= $_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE']){
            if($_FILES[$imagen]['error']){
                switch($_FILES[$imagen]['error']){
                    case 1 | 2: //1- peso másimo servidor - 2 -  peso másimo del formulario. En este caso ambos son iguales
                        echo "<p>El tamaño excede el permitido por el servidor o el del formulario.</p>";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        echo "<p>El envío del archivo se interrumpió o el archivo está dañado.</p>";
                }
            }else {//En teoría no existe error de momento con la  subida  de la imagen al servidor...
                if($_FILES[$imagen]['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
                    $destino_ruta = "../../" . IMAGENES;
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$imagen]['tmp_name'],$destino_ruta . $_FILES[$imagen]['name']);
                    switch ($imagen){
                        case $imagenes[0]:
                            $miProducto->setImagenPrincipal($_FILES[$imagen]['name']);
                            break;
                        case $imagenes[1]:
                            $miProducto->setImagen2($_FILES[$imagen]['name']);
                            break;
                        case $imagenes[2]:
                            $miProducto->setImagen3($_FILES[$imagen]['name']);
                            break;
                        case $imagenes[3]:
                            $miProducto->setImagen4($_FILES[$imagen]['name']);
                            break;
                        case $imagenes[4]:
                            $miProducto->setImagen5($_FILES[$imagen]['name']);
                            break;
                        case $imagenes[5]:
                            $miProducto->setImagen5($_FILES[$imagen]['name']);
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "<p>Ha habido algún error tratando de subir al archivo al directorio de imágenes.</p>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

if(($_POST['NombreProducto'] != "") && (sizeof($_POST['NombreProducto']) > 0)){
    $miProducto->setNombre(htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['NombreProducto']), ENT_QUOTES));
} else {
    ?>  <script>
            alert("¡No puedes subir un producto sin nombre!");
            window.location="../../NuevoProducto.php";
        </script>   <?php
}

if(($_POST['Categoria'] != "") && (sizeof($_POST['Categoria']) > 0)){
    $miProducto->setCategoria(htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['Categoria']), ENT_QUOTES));
} else {
    ?>  <script>
            alert("¡No puedes subir un producto sin categoría!");
            window.location="../../NuevoProducto.php";
        </script>   <?php
}

if(($_POST['Subcategoria'] != "") && (sizeof($_POST['Subcategoria']) > 0)){
    $miProducto->setSubcategoria(htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['Subcategoria']), ENT_QUOTES));
}

if(($_POST['Familia'] != "") && (sizeof($_POST['Familia']) > 0)){
    $miProducto->setFamilia(htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['Familia']), ENT_QUOTES));
}

if(($_POST['DescripcionCorta'] != "") && (sizeof($_POST['DescripcionCorta']) > 0)){
    $miProducto->setDescripcionCorta(htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['DescripcionCorta']), ENT_QUOTES));
} else {
    ?>  <script>
            alert("¡No puedes subir un producto sin DESCRIPCIÓN CORTA!");
            window.location="../../NuevoProducto.php";
        </script>   <?php
}

if(($_POST['DescripcionLarga'] != "") && (sizeof($_POST['DescripcionLarga']) > 0)){
    $miProducto->setDescripcionLarga($_POST['DescripcionLarga']);
} else {
    ?>  <script>
            alert("¡No puedes subir un producto sin DESCRIPCIÓN LARGA!");
            window.location="../../NuevoProducto.php";
        </script>   <?php
}

if(floatval($_POST['Precio']) > 0){
    $miProducto->setPrecio(floatval($_POST['Precio']));
} else {
    ?>  <script>
            alert("¡No puedes subir un producto sin PRECIO!");
            window.location="../../NuevoProducto.php";
        </script>   <?php
}

if((floatval($_POST['PrecioAnterior']) > 0) && (floatval($_POST["Precio"]) < floatval($_POST["PrecioAnterior"]))){
    $miProducto->setPrecioAnterior(floatval($_POST['PrecioAnterior']));
} elseif((floatval($_POST["PrecioAnterior"]) > 0) && (floatval($_POST["Precio"]) >= (floatval($_POST["PrecioAnterior"])))){
    ?>  <script>
            alert("¡No puedes subir un producto cuyo PRECIO sea MAYOR o igual que su PRECIO ANTERIOR!");
            window.location="../../NuevoProducto.php";
        </script>   <?php
}elseif((floatval($_POST["PrecioAnterior"]) > 0) && (floatval($_POST["Precio"]) == 0)){
    ?>  <script>
            alert("¡No puedes rellenar el PRECIO ANTERIOR sin haber rellenado el PRECIO.!");
            window.location="../../NuevoProducto.php";
        </script>   <?php
}

if((floatval($_POST['Precio3U']) > 0) && (floatval($_POST["Precio3U"]) < floatval($_POST["Precio"]))){
    $miProducto->setPrecioU3U(floatval($_POST['Precio3U']));
} else {
    ?>  <script>
            alert("¡No puedes subir un producto sin precio por llevar 5 unidades o con precio unitario por 5  unidades IGUAL O MAYOR al precio actual!");
            window.location="../../NuevoProducto.php";
        </script>   <?php
}

if((floatval($_POST['Precio5U']) > 0) && (floatval($_POST["Precio5U"]) < floatval($_POST["Precio3U"]))){
    $miProducto->setPrecioU5U(floatval($_POST['Precio5U']));
} else {
    ?>  <script>
            alert("¡No puedes subir un producto cuyo precio unitario al llevarse 5 unidades sea IGUAL O MAYOR al precio  unitario al llevarse 3 unidades!");
            window.location="../../NuevoProducto.php";
        </script>   <?php
}

$miProducto->setStock(intval($_POST['Stock']));

if($_POST['Destacado'] == "on"){
    $miProducto->setDestacado(1);
} else {
    echo "<p>No es un producto destacado.</p>";
    $miProducto->setDestacado(0);
}

if($_POST['Video'] != "") {
    $encontrar = "http://";
    $encontrar2 = "https://";
    $comparar = substr_compare($_POST['Video'], $encontrar, 0, 6);
    $comparar2 = substr_compare($_POST['Video'], $encontrar2, 0, 6);

    if ($comparar == true || $comparar2 == true) {
        $miProducto->setVideo($_POST["Video"]);
    } else {
        ?>  <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("El VIDEO tiene que comenzar por <?php echo $encontrar ?> o por <?php echo $encontrar ?>.");
                window.location="../Vista/prueba_editor.html";
        </script> <?php
    }
}

$miProducto->setAhorros();
$miCRUD->setProducto($miProducto);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

estuve revisando tu consulta, la modifiqué y vinculé los valores que quieres insertar a los parametros de la consulta que sería el simbolo "?", lo cambié por nombres para que sea mas legible y claro, espero que no te importe, igual puedes modificar el ejemplo hecho aqui con tu consulta, espero ayudarte:

```
public function setProducto(Producto_Modelo $producto){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->TablaDb 
    (NOMBREPRODUCTO, 
    CATEGORIA, SUBCATEGORIA, FAMILIAPRODUCTO,
    DESCRIPCIONCORTA, DESCRIPCIONLARGA, 
    PRECIO, PRECIOANTERIOR, PRECIOINDI3U, PRECIOINDI5U, STOCK, 
    DESTACADO, VIDEO,
    IMAGENPRINCIPAL, IMAGEN2, IMAGEN3, IMAGEN4, IMAGEN5, IMAGEN6) 
    VALUES (
    :nombre, 
    :categoria, :subcategoria, :familiaProducto, 
    :descripcionCorta, :descripcionLarga, 
    :precio, :precioAnterior, :precioIndi3U, :precioIndi5U, :stock, 
    :destacado, :video, 
    :imagenPrincipal, :imagen2, :imagen3, :imagen4, :imagen5, :imagen6)";

    $preparar = $this->Conexion->prepare($sql);

    $preparar->bindValue(':nombre', $producto->getNombre(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':categoria', $producto->getCategoria(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $preparar->bindValue(':subcategoria', $producto->getSubcategoria(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $preparar->bindValue(':familiaProducto', $producto->getFamilia(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $preparar->bindValue(':descripcionCorta', $producto->getDescripcionCorta(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':descripcionLarga', $producto->getDescripcionLarga(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':precio', $producto->getPrecio(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':precioAnterior', $producto->getPrecioAnterior(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':precioIndi3U', $producto->getPrecioU3U(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':precioIndi5U', $producto->getPrecioU5U(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':stock', $producto->getStock(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':destacado', $producto->getDestacado(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':video',  $producto->getVideo(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':imagenPrincipal', $producto->getImagenPrincipal(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':imagen2', $producto->getImagen2(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':imagen3', $producto->getImagen3(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':imagen4', $producto->getImagen4(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':imagen5', $producto->getImagen5(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $preparar->bindValue(':imagen6', $producto->getImagen6(), PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if ($preparar->execute()) {
        echo "¡<p>Se ha insertado correctamente el nuevo producto!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Ha habido algún error intentando insertar el nuevo producto.</p>";
    }
}
```

bindValue en las consultas con PDO en PHP permite vincula un valor a un parámetro.

¿Qué quiere decir?

Que en vez de poner en la consulta el parametro ? puedes asignar uno con el nombre que quieras y le da mas legibilidad a la consulta, ejemplo:

```
$nombre = 'pepe';

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre) VALUES (:miNombre)";

$preparar = $this->Conexion->prepare($sql);

$preparar->bindValue(':miNombre', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$preparar->execute();
```

En este ejemplo el parametro vinculado es ":miNombre" y el dato a insertar es la variable $nombre, el tercer parametro es para especificar el tipo de dato, que puede ser (como en este caso tipo String)  PARAM_STR, PARAM_INT,ETC. Vea los tipos en [Constantes predefinidas pág oficial PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.constants.php)

Comment: Muchas  gracias.  No me  importa,  si eso puede hacer para que funcione... Al  contrario,  lo agradezco. Pero  según el enlace adjunto, no veo ningún PDO::PARAM_ que  sea para los decimales  o floats... En el caso de Destacado me serviría `PDO::PARAM_BOOL`, el `PDO::PARAM_INT` para el  Stock y para casi todo lo demás, el `PDO::PARAM_STR`... ¿Alguna forma de hacerlo para los precios?

Comment: Yo para precios uso PDO::PARAM_STR, pero igual puede que haya alguien por aquí que lo haga de una forma distinta.

Comment: Ok. Más que nada lo digo porque en la base  de datos están configurados como decimal(6,2) y deduzco que no aceptará que le envíe strings...

Comment: Al final lo he hecho como tú y no parece darme  ningún error... ¡Muchasgracias!  :)